# here is my c function prog it takes use void msg two times?

Tags: c, printf, program-entry-point, void, getch

Here is a c function program. It looks to take void msg() function void main() function. how is the void msg() function used two times.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>


void msg();

void main()
{
 printf("Hello All\n");


 msg();
}








void msg()
{
 printf("\n TheCrazyProgrammer");

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void msg()` should be `void msg(void)` both times. This explicitly states that `msg` takes no arguments. And `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. If you have a book that told you to use `void main()`, you need a better book.

Comment: Smells of Borland Turbo C.